# run matlab function and a java thread in parallel

Tags: java, matlab

how can i run a Matlab function and a java thread in parallel.
I want to run a camera acquisition function which acquires frames and saves them at location and a java thread which accesses the frames.
Also, i need to know how to synchronize these threads.

Comment: Have you checked [undocumented matlab](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/explicit-multi-threading-in-matlab-part1)? This awesome website contains much information on this type of problems.